# How do I find the determinant of a 2x2 matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, determinants

It has to be a*d-b*c Here is my code but it says that a aList is not defined

```
def findDeterminate(alist):
    value=0
    aList = [[a,b],[c,d]]
    for i in range (0, len(aList)):
        value = aList[0][1]*aList[1][2] - aList[0][2]*aList[1][1]

def main():
    a = str(input("what is your first value"))
    b = str(input('what is your second value'))
    c = str(input('what is your third value'))
    d = str(input('what is your fourth value'))
    return findDeterminate(aList)
```

Comment: The `for` loop does nothing, get rid of it.  The `findDeterminate()` function does not return a value.  The `str()` function creates strings, you want `float()` instead.  The `aList` assignment should be moved to `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

I won't solve this for you, but will give some hints:

- There is no `aList` in `main()`.
- You've misspelt `aList` as `alist` in the definition of
  `findDeterminate()`.
- What's the purpose of the `for` loop?
- A two-element list has no element at index `2`.
- You are not returning anything from `findDeterminate()`.
- `main()` has no special meaning in Python and is not called automatically.

(BTW, the determinant of a matrix is spelled "determinant" and not "determinate".)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Determinant of a 2x2 matrix
matrixG = [[2, 1],
           [3, 4]]

if len(matrixG) != 2 or len(matrixG[0]) != 2:
    print("Matrix should be 2x2 matrix only")
else:
    determinant = (matrixG[0][0] * matrixG[1][1]) - (matrixG[0][1] * matrixG[1][0])
    print(determinant)
```